# Trying to create a code that print absolute path and last modify time of file

Tags: c, directory, getcwd, cwd

**WHAT I HAVE TO DO**

I have to find, starting from a directory, a file located in one of all directories that have as root the directory passed in input.
Something as shell command `find`.

**INPUT/OUTPUT**

Having this in input:

```
./myfind /home/claudio/Scrivania file.txt
```

I need something as this in output, absolute path and last modify date ecc:

```
/home/claudio/Scrivania/SistemiOperativi/file.txt   Tue Mar 30 19:51:54 2021
```

**MY CODE**
It doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#if !defined(NAME_MAX)
#define NAME_MAX 256
#endif

void find(const char* passed_dir_name, const char* passed_file_name) {
    if (chdir(passed_dir_name) == -1) {
        perror("FATAL ERROR CHANGING DIRECTORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    DIR* current_directory;
    if ((current_directory = opendir(".")) == NULL) {
        perror("FATAL ERROR OPENING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char* buf;
    if ((buf = calloc(NAME_MAX, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        perror("FATAL ERROR ALLOCATING MEMORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct dirent* dir;
    while ((dir = readdir(current_directory)) != NULL) {
        struct stat statbuf;
        stat(dir->d_name, &statbuf);
        if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            if (strncmp(dir->d_name, ".", 1) != 0 && strncmp(dir->d_name, "..", 2) != 0) {
                find(dir->d_name, passed_file_name);
            }
        } else {
            if (strncmp(dir->d_name, passed_file_name, strlen(passed_file_name) == 0)) {
                if (getcwd(buf, NAME_MAX) == NULL) {
                    perror("FATAL ERROR");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            fprintf(stdout, "%s/%s     %s", buf, dir->d_name, ctime(&statbuf.st_mtime));   
            }
        }
    }
    if (closedir(current_directory) == -1) {
        perror("FATAL ERROR CLOSING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }  
    chdir("..");
    free(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: RUn as ./myfind directory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char* dir = argv[1];
    const char* file = argv[2];
    struct stat statbuf;
    stat(dir, &statbuf);
    if(!S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FATAL ERROR: %s IS NOT A DIRECTORY\n", dir);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    find(dir, file);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Specifically, have you run through your code in a debugger? After doing that you should be able to tell us the exact line of code where things first start to go wrong. Even if you don't understand why you should be able to pin point where.

Comment: @kaylum With GDB it never seems to enter this `else`:

`else {
            if (strncmp(dir->d_name, passed_file_name, strlen(passed_file_name) == 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong in:

```
if (strncmp(dir->d_name, passed_file_name, strlen(passed_file_name) == 0))
```

You need to write:

```
if (strncmp(dir->d_name, passed_file_name, strlen(passed_file_name)) == 0)
```

Since `strncmp(x, y, 0)` will always return 0, the condition is never being met.

But note that there's no point in using `strncmp` here at all.  `strncmp` is only needed if you don't know that one of your entries is a null terminated string.  You have a guarante that `d_name` is null-terminated, and if `passed_file_name` is not, then `strlen` is going to be problematic.  You might as well just write `strcmp(dir->d_name, passed_file_name)`.